# Get the hashtag using twitter gem

Tags: ruby, twitter, hash, rubygems

I am using ***twitter gem*** to stream tweets in ruby.
My code is

```
client.filter(:track => topics.join(",")) do |object|
  if(object.is_a?(Twitter::Entities))
  puts object.text if object.is_a?(Twitter::Tweet)
  puts object.created_at
  puts object.hashtags.to_s
  puts object.user.name
end
end
```

I need to fetch the **hashtags** in the tweet, if i use the above code I am getting the output as

```
 [#<Twitter::Entity::Hashtag:0x007ff23a06d4c8 @attrs={:text=>"coffee", :indices=>[20, 27]}>, #<Twitter::Entity::Hashtag:0x007ff23a06d450 @attrs={:text=>"mornings", :indices=>[28, 37]}>, #<Twitter::Entity::Hashtag:0x007ff23a06d428 @attrs={:text=>"cantstopmoving", :indices=>[38, 53]}>]
```

is there a way to fetch the individual hashtags

Answer (score 0):

```
object.hashtags.each do |p|
  puts "HashTags " +p.text.to_s
end
```

Comment: When the tweet shows an ellipsis, the field to check (hashtags) is nested inside the "extended tweet" field. I can't find the method to access it so I resorted to converting the whole Twitter::Tweet object to a hash.