# Twitter API doesn't return full text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, twitter

I am using the twitter gem to retrieve tweets. If I am pulling this tweet https://twitter.com/_SCesports/status/959540058343854080, you notice that he puts the hashtags #EULCS and #lolesports at the end. However, in my tweet object I am unable to grab those hashtags.

This is my tweet object

```
tweet.full_text
-> ".@G2esports evolve to G2-3 with a win over @Splyce \n\nIn over 40+ minutes we had a grand total of 9 kills...\n\nIsn't… <tweet url shortner, unable to post because of stackoverflow>"
```

I want it to include those hashtags at the end.

Comment: which twitter gem do you use? anyway, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018207/get-the-hashtag-using-twitter-gem) might help you

Comment: i use this https://github.com/sferik/twitter. Thanks that link helped!